# Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS onto SSD, install-grub /dev/sda2 failed

Tags: partitioning, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS onto a SSD hard drive, and am failing.

After some troubleshooting online, this is my approach.

1. Burn Ubuntu ISO onto USB flash drive using Rufus (GPT format).
2. Boot onto the flash drive in UEFI mode, when presented by Grub Menu, I edit
   the command and add acpi=off nomodeset to be able to boot onto the flash drive
3. Select Try Ubuntu, from there, I click on the installer icon on the desktop.
4. I select "Something else" and partition my hard drive to have 500 MB of primary
   EFI, 16000 MB of primary swap, and the rest of the hard drive EXT4 primary mounted
   on /. For the drop down at the bottom, I select the device for booatload to be
   sda (my hard drive).
5. After doing this, I check the current mount using findmnt.
   /target/boot/efi has /dev/sda1 (EFI partition on hard drive).
6. Install fails at "executing install-grub /dev/sda2 failed this is a critical error"

I get the error failed to register the EFI boot entry : Operation not permitted

Do you guys have any suggestions? I really don't know why the grub install is failing...

Comment: I am installing this on a fresh (well - now semi-installed on) SSD. My goal will is to have two separate hard drives, one running Windows 10 and the other Ubuntu. Though for now, the SSD I'm trying to install on is the only one in the computer. And, in my #4 I did mean sda (my bad!). I tried the fresh-install (Erase everything and install Ubuntu), and I get the same grub error. Any more ideas?

Comment: No, it did not. I read both forums, and applied both solutions. I installed Windows to the SSD, and then attempted to wipe it with the Linux install, but still run into the same "executing install-grub /dev/sda failed. error", I then attempted to wipe it using GParted and the installer UI, and this resulted in the same error. I used different USB's as well. This is the 5th different USB I've attempted. Any other ideas?